# Xstream append to existing XML file

Tags: java, xstream

First let me say I am very new to Java. I've been trying to figure out how to append a chunk of XML to an existing XML file using Xstream.

Example XML:

```
<root>
    <first>
        <a>Some Value</a>
        <b>Some Value B</b>
    </first
    <second>
        <a>Another Value</a>
        <b>Another Value B</b>
    </second>
</root>
```

How would I go about appending the following using Xstream?

```
<third>
    <a>More A</a>
    <b>More B</b>
</third>
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you followed the two minute tutorial of Xstream yet? This can be found [here](http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html).

You should address some implementation choices first: which way to go with Xstream?
For example: is the XML document a large document or a small document (if small, you could use a DomDriver.If large, use a StaxDriver)?

Does your XML document uses namespaces? If so, be aware that not all Xstream parsers implement namespace awareness, see the Xstream [faq](http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#XML_namespaces).

More information can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xstream/) to get you started.

Please provide us your SSCCE so that users can try out your code example.
See details on how to write a SSCCE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) and [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/sscce.html)

Also include a small valid XML file in your SSCCE.